# Select matching pairs of attributes from related table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is books, the other is editions. Each edition has an attribute like "hardback" or "paperback" in a column "edtype". There can be multiple edition rows related to each book row.

```
select books.id, books.name, editions.id, editions.edtype from books
join editions on books.id=editions.bookid;
```

would return something like:

```
1  name1  1  hardback
1  name1  2  paperback
2  name2  3  paperback
3  name3  4  hardback
```

What I want to be able to do is find books that have (1) both a hardback and paperback edition:

```
1  name1
```

(2) A paperback but not a hardback edition

```
2  name2
```

(3) A hardback but not a paperback edition

```
3  name3
```

I have the following query, which I think does (1), but I'm not quite convinced (because the number of rows it returns appears too low):

```
select id, name
from books
left join  editions e1 on ( books.id = e1.bookid and e1.edtype = 'paperback')
left join  editions e2 on ( books.id = e2.bookid and e2.edtype = 'hardback')
where e1.edtype is not null
and e2.edtype is not null
group by b_id
;
```

While I'm looking at just two attributes right now, it would be nice to be able to expand that to multiple matching attributes in the editions table.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your query, improved a bit to use table aliases and have distinct column names:

```
select b.id as book_id, b.name, e.id as edition_id, e.edtype
from books b join
     editions e
     on b.id = e.bookid;
```

You want to find books, so that suggests aggregation by books.  Then we need to do something to understand the `edtype`.  Try this:

```
select b.id as book_id, b.name,
       (case when min(edtype) = max(edtype)
             then min(edtype)
             else 'Both'
        end) as EdTypes
from books b join
     editions e
     on b.id = e.bookid;
group by b.id, b.name;
```

Comment: That is quite a good solution, in that it runs quickly and identifies books having the max and min, or max or min edtypes, but, the edtypes as a whole are a larger set than "hardback" and "paperback". There probably is no limit to the number/range of edtype attributes, but I have around 6 at the moment: ebook, hardback, large print, paperpback, POD, unknown. So you can see that min/max won't identify "hardback/paperback". I may also need to find, at other times, where there are ebook editions of a book, but no paperpack edition, or paperbacks with no ebooks, or those that have both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following Gordon's code above I put in a couple of sub queries, and I think this does what I need (at least if I am only comparing two attributes):

```
select * from (
   select books.name, bookid, (case when min(edtype) = max(edtype)
         then min(edtype)
         else 'Both'
    end) as EdTypes
   from
       (select * from editions where (edtype = 'paperback' or edtype = 'hardback'))
     as e2
     join books on e2.bookid = books.id
     group by bookid
    ) as titlelist
 where edtypes = 'Both';
```

So, first select rows that are exclusively the ones you are interested in - so you have a min and max that makes sense. Then process with the case statement, join to books and eliminate duplicates. Then select each type in turn to get a count.